# why does boost compilation fails with clang?

Tags: boost, compilation, clang, boost-build

I am trying to compile boost C++ using clang.

```
./b2 --prefix=~/boost --includedir=~/boost/include --libdir=~/boost/lib toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -isystem ~/libcxx/include/" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++ -L ~/libcxx/lib/"
```

When I see log file it gives error saying

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  __GLOBAL__I_a in exceptions.o
 "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  __GLOBAL__I_a in exceptions.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my default clang is clang-mp-3.3. Can anyone please help me figure out what this problem is.

Comment: What's the platform? What's Boost version?

Comment: thank you Igor R for the comment . what do you mean by platform(sorry)? Its boost 1.55. I have mac darwin Kernel version 12.4.0

Comment: Boost 1.55 doesn't exists, perhaps you mean 1.54. What symbols the linker can't find?

Comment: @Igor R let me get back to you after I compile again removing :    -isystem ~/libcxx/include/ and -L ~/libcxx/lib/

Comment: @Igor R I have edited the question of what the linker error about. Is that what you are looking for .. cause when I tried removing -isystem ~/libcxx/include/ and -L ~/libcxx/lib/  the error persist :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the reason of error in the web I found [this](http://hnrkptrsn.github.io/2013/02/26/c11-and-boost-setup-guide/) which explain about compiling boost with clang. I am not sure why adding **define=BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED** made it worked. Please do comment anyone who knows why it worked.  I was then able to compile with no error but I still see some warnings but it worked for me for now.

The default clang I am using is (clang-mp-3.3)

$ clang -v

clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix

```
 ./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang --without-libraries=mpi,python,graph_parallel
 ./b2 clean
 ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"  linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"  define=BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
```